# Too many template parameters in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

<>I use C++ and plan a library with classes that have about 100 template parameters. Of course, I worried that having n template parameters, if the user needs every combination, we have 2^n different classes, which is a kind of code explosion. However, a user would need to do 2^n instantiations for that.

My question is: What are the main *technical* issues with so many template parameters?

Notes:

- With *technical*, I am not interested in subjective answers concerning readability, design etc. I mean facts like

  - runtime
  - code size
  - maximum number of templates allowed

Code sample:

```
// here we have 2, but I have 100 template parameters
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class Class
{
    T1 x;
    T2 y;
    int add(T1 _x, T2 _y) { return _x+_y; } // 4 instanciations possible?
    Class<T2, T1>* swap() { return new Class<T2, T1>(); } // always 2 instanciations?
};
```

Comment: You can’t just discard design considerations. This *is* bad design, partially *because of* technical limitations.

Comment: You really need to clarify what you mean by "100 template parameters". The imagine I have in mind is a template with 100 template parameters. In Texas, we have a time for that kind of design: Get a rope.

Comment: I wouldn't like to maintain this code....

Comment: How do you calculate the number of combinations to be `2^n`? This is only true if each of your `n` parameters can take only two different values (for instance if they are booleans). The correct number of potential instantiations is `k^n`, where `n` is the number of parameters and `k` is the number of values these parameters can take. Since you state your `n` ~ 100, your user will never be able to use all combinations. Why don't you tell us the actual problem your library tries to solve with so many template paramaters? Perhaps we could propose more viable alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main consideration would be code size, and that can have an impact on performance. Each different template instantiation will require the generation of all of the member functions that are used (or all, if the user does manual template instantiation). There will be no code reuse among the different template instantiations.

Besides that, any element for which you provide a large number of arguments is hard to deal with. From the maintenance point of view, a declaration with 10 arguments is already hard to read. It will either extend multiple lines or else extend very wide in the line and it will be hard to determine by inspection that all arguments are in the correct position. *Is that X the 7th or 8th argument?* Yes, you can count them, but it becomes painful. If the number of arguments is 100, the problem is just exacerbated.

Why do you want all those to be template arguments? Without any more information you will not get other suggestions, but there are most probably other designs for the same problem that don't require that level of complexity. Maybe the arguments need not be known at compile time (they can be passed to functions/constructors in the form of arrays/vectors for non-type arguments), or maybe they can be grouped (one type template argument holding a set of related typedefs)...

Comment: Yeah, grouping was my idea, too. When you pass `std::string`, you have hidden the `char` parameter - like that. But from what you write, do you think the code explosion might get exponential (even with a linear amount of instanciations and members)?

Comment: @Johannes: It depends on your code. If there is going to be a single specialization, no there will not be a code explosion. If every object in the program has a slightly different set of template arguments, then the functions used will be generated for each object and there will be a code explosion. The number of unique template instantiations in the program does not directly depend on the number of template arguments, although the presence of more arguments means that there are more options for that to happen.

Comment: Thanks, I have need environment with a lot template parameters but they are naturally grouped into slices so groping will do it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Actually templated class types are determined at compile time. This does not mean that you have 2^n different classes but instead you have only n classes. At compile time the appropriate types are replaced and the class members/functions are only of the type that you are using them with.

E.g.

```
template <class Type1, class Type2>
class A
{
private:
    Type1 member_x;
public:
    Type2 GetTypeValue(Type1, Type2);
};
```

When instantiated like this:

```
A<int, string> *x = new A<int, string>();
```

Is being compiled only as a class with an integer type member and a string type member. Same stands for functions, etc.

**Update:**
With the updated example below you would still have only one instance of the function and it would be a `string` returning function taking parameters `int` and `string`.

Comment: Okay, but If we have `Type1 member_x` and `Type2 member_x`, and have a member function that uses both, might we not get 4 member functions?

Comment: @Johannes I have edited the post with additional explanation for your question. Again everything is performed at compile time.

Comment: @KonstantinD-Infragistics I see your example. But imagine something tricky like if `GetTypeValue()` would return an Object of `class A` with different template parameters... for example it could just swap int and string, so it would return `A<string, int>()` (example added above). Are you really sure that a code explosion is unlikely?

Comment: Yeah, I think that way, we would get the whole symmetric group S_n with 2n member functions and only one instantiation, right?

Comment: @Johannes again it's dependent on the specific implementation. The template class if not used is completely ignored by the compiler. If your code utilizes the whole plethora of possibilities for the template types then you can get a lot of different instances of member functions.

Answer (score 2):

There is a reason to do that.   Auto code generator for
Serialization, Parsing, Documentation, Intellisense.  all headers would be able to be parsed, then auto written as a second class that has template members for each member function of the parsed class.  Since an auto code system would write the code, readability would not be important, yet you could access whatever class member, regardless of size or indirection from some branching code based on the type each template member is that is a base class of every auto generated templated class.

Then when using the class you could have functions to write out for each 'type' by looking at type, or you could display values for each template type as an output to a parser or IDE display.  And of coarse, the intellisence would be completely precompiled making for fast searching.  Simply have a parallel project that compiles on change in a header file then it can look up various characteristics regardless of what type of class member it is.

Technically speaking it removes type from the entire problem of parsing, documenting, outputting or displaying items in a class and does it at compile time of some program that looks at some files.  Because each member has a way of seeing type (similar to why compilers like it better when static_cast is used instead of c style cast)

code size would be the same size as files parsed 1-1 per class, advantage would be any program memory space, could be cast to your auto written type that matches it and then accessed with functions that are type aware to display manipulate or output values.  Imagine how convenient intelliscense would be if simply finding a 'class' in some file allowed it to access all the information in that class without any parsing only needing a cast to your precreated class in template form, where the base class of the auto generated class had methods to manipulate data on now detectable types.

Probably what he is doing with 100 plus template arguments